# Directly reference a method on DbContext using WCF Data Services?

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, entity-framework-5

Good afternoon fellow stackers (or overflowers, whichever you prefer), this is more of a cleanliness and convenience issue than anything else but I can't imagine that I'm the only one who's ever wondered about it so here we go...

I've got a basic OData enabled WCF Data Service class that's using my Entity Framework data context.

```cs
[JsonpSupportBehavior]
public class ControlBindingService : DataService<MyDataContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.DataServiceBehavior.AcceptCountRequests = true;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);          
    }

    protected override MyDataContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The WCF Data Services implementation must be hosted in IIS.");

        string username;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        else
        {
            // The request didn't have user identity, attempt to find UserName in the 
            // request header before returning 401 to the caller.
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["UserName"]))
            {
                username = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["UserName"];
                // REVIEW: We should validate user before passing it to the datacontext.
            }
            else
                throw new DataServiceException(401, "Client did not pass required authentication information.");
        }

        return MyDataContext.GetInstance(username);
    }

    [WebGet]
    public List<DailyKeyPerformanceIndicator> GetResourceKPIs(
        int resourceId, string jsonStart, string jsonEnd, int scenarioId)
    {
        DateTime start = jsonStart.DeserializeJson<DateTime>();
        DateTime end = jsonEnd.DeserializeJson<DateTime>();

        if (scenarioId < 1)
        {
            scenarioId = CurrentDataSource.GetScenarios()
                .Single(s => s.IsProduction).ScenarioID;
        }

        return CurrentDataSource.GetDailyResourceKPI(
            scenarioId, start, end, resourceId);
    }
}
```

The data context is just a standard (code-first) `DbContext` implementation with properties exposing the entity sets, etc..

However, we also have methods on there to expose some tables that we wanted to enforce some constraints upon. Specifically (see code below), we want to know what the caller wants to use the data for so we can return only the appropriate results. For example, if the caller wants to get rows from the employees table--they may want to get all rows, or only rows that they have update privileges for.

```cs
[Serializable]
public partial class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    static MyDataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDataContext>(null);
    }

    public MyDataContext()
        : base("name=MyDBString")
    { }

    // Standard table properties...

    public DbSet<User> Users
    {
        get { return this.Set<User>(); }
    }

    public DbSet<UserSetting> UserSettings
    {
        get { return this.Set<UserSetting>(); }
    }

    public DbSet<SettingDefinition> SettingDefinitions
    {
        get { return this.Set<SettingDefinition>(); }
    }       

// Restricted table methods...

public DbSet<Client> GetClients(
    DatabasePermissions perms = DatabasePermissions.Select)
{
   // getPermissibleSet is a method in a helper class that does some 
   // magical querying and produces a filtered DbSet.
   return getPermissibleSet<Client>(perms);
}

public DbSet<Employee> GetEmployees(
    DatabasePermissions perms = DatabasePermissions.Select)
{
   // getPermissibleSet is a method in a helper class that does some 
   // magical querying and produces a filtered DbSet.
   return getPermissibleSet<Employee>(perms);
}       
}
```

Now to the root of the issue... What I'd like to avoid having to do is writing a `[WebGet]` for each and every "restricted table method" on my data context. The reason is really nothing more than redundancy--the `[WebGet]` method would end up being a direct pass-through to the data context.

So in summary, I'd say what I'm basically looking to do is to mark methods from my data context class that WCF will expose in the same way it does for my DbSet properties. Any takers?

Thanks! J

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. I'm trying to do similar things. This is kind of throwing a dart here but have you tried something like this? You should probably separate the generics out so you don't create a unique context with each type, but it seems like you should be able to get rid of the duplicate code with generics.

```
[Serializable]
public partial class MyDataContext<T> : DbContext where T : class
{
    static MyDataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDataContext>(null);
    }

    public MyDataContext()
        : base("name=MyDBString")
    { }

    // Standard table properties...

    public DbSet<T> SettingDefinitions
    {
        get { return this.Set<T>(); }
    }

    // Restricted table methods...

    public DbSet<T> GetClients(
        DatabasePermissions perms = DatabasePermissions.Select)
    {
        // getPermissibleSet is a method in a helper class that does some 
        // magical querying and produces a filtered DbSet.
        return getPermissibleSet<T>(perms);
    }
}
```